Why don't I have the flashlight or camera buttons on my 2022 iPhone SE lock screen with iOS 18?
I was reading about the iOS 18 changes and how you can change/remove the flashlight and camera buttons on the lock screen.  Which confused the heck out of me because I have never seen those on my lock screen!
I currently have a 2022 iPhone SE which I upgraded to iOS18 the other day.  Both before and after the upgrade I did not have those buttons on my lock screen.  I've gone to “Settings > Touch ID & Passcode” and verified that both “Control Center” and “Lock Screen Widgets” are turned on under “Allow access when locked.”
I've tried editing my lock screen both from the lock screen and from “Settings > Wallpaper” and those buttons in the bottom corners that I see in all the guides just aren't there, nor is there any affordance to add them.
I've even added a new iOS 18 lock screen (in case there's something weird about mine, as it's been carried over from phone to phone via restoring from backups for quite some time) and that doesn't have the buttons either.
I asked some friends if there's some thing where Touch ID phones don't have them on the lock screen and they said they had them on their Touch ID phones, including someone with an iPhone SE!
So what the heck is going on with my phone? Or are those buttons in fact not on phones with a Touch ID home button and they were confused about what I was asking about?
